# displays a list of students who have the maximum average score

Tags: sql-server

1) There are two tables that were created by scripts below; you are tasked to write the SQL query that displays a list of students who have the maximum average score. Please, provide two solutions with the following limitations 
 a)  You can use neither subqueries nor cursors nor additional tables
 b)  You can use neither subqueries nor cursors nor additional tables nor GROUP BY clause

```
create table Students
(ID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
 StudentName varchar(200) not null,
 );

create table StudentMarks
(ID int identity (1,1) primary key not null,
 Student_ID int not null references Students (ID),
 Mark int not null check (mark between 1 and 5));

 insert into Students 
 (StudentName)
 values 
 ('Ivanov'),
 ('Petrov'),
 ('Sydorov'),
 ('Semenov');


 insert into StudentMarks
 (Student_ID,Mark)
 values
 (1,3), (1,4), (1,3), (1,5),
 (2,3), (2,4), (2,3), (2,5),
 (3,3), (3,3), (3,5), (3,3)
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
select Student_ID 
from StudentMarks 
where MAX(AVG(Mark))=AVG(Mark) 
GROUP BY Student_ID
```

Comment: The *you are tasked to write the SQL query that...* kinda gives away that this is homework. Also, wich version of SQL Server?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Please post your code so far; you will get better answers if you demonstrate that you are trying to solve the problem yourself and not simply asking others to solve it for you.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for someone to complete your homework

Comment: select Student_ID from StudentMarks
where MAX(AVG(Mark))=AVG(Mark)
GROUP BY Student_ID